# Android Disable all buttons

Tags: java, android

I programmatically am creating buttons as depending on certain factors their will either be 3 or 4 buttons.

In some instances I would like to create all of the buttons but disable them all. At the moment the problem I have is that I cannot access the buttons from outside of this loop

```
    if (4val != null && 4val.length() > 0){
        Button b4 = new Button(this);
        b4.setText(answer4val);
        b4.setTextSize(18);
        layout.addView(b4, layoutParams);
        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reason(4);
            }
        });
    }
```

I would like to disable / enable all of the buttons outside of these if statements. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare them in a wider scopre (maybe as class members):

```
// in the class scope
Button b4 = null;

// in the method scope
if (4val != null && 4val.length() > 0){
    b4 = new Button(this);
    b4.setText(answer4val);
    b4.setTextSize(18);
    layout.addView(b4, layoutParams);
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reason(4);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the buttons in that loop. Make the buttons fields for the class and you can access them throughout the class. Then just initialize them in that loop.

If you only need them in one method you can make them local to the method rather than fields for the class.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can save the Buttons in an List and do stuff on them later on

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

if (4val != null && 4val.length() > 0){
    Button b4 = new Button(this);
    b4.setText(answer4val);
    b4.setTextSize(18);
    layout.addView(b4, layoutParams);
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reason(4);
        }
    });
    buttons.add(b4);
}

foreach(Button b : buttons) {
  b.setEnable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the Buttons you have two option methods depending of how you want to disable them:

```
 button.setClickable(false);
 button.setVisibility(int visibility);
```

the first will make the setOnCLickListener useless
The second will set the parameter Visibility to "visible", "invisible", or "gone"

to disable them outside the loop also you have to initialize them before, and  add

```
b4.setId();
```

before adding it to the view